# In Vue 3, how to make v-model work within a router template?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I use [Vue Router 4](https://router.vuejs.org) on Vue 3 with templates to serve a a simple page.

I'm trying to get v-model to work within the template. You can see my working version [here](https://dcycle.github.io/tutorial-echarts-and-vue/input-binding.html#/).

Everything binds well, excite the input tag within the templates used by the routes (`<input v-model="input_binding" placeholder="edit me" />` binds correctly outside the route templates, but just acts as an empty input element within the templates).

Here is my HTML:

```
<input v-model="input_binding" placeholder="edit me" />
<p>Message (outside route) is: {{ input_binding }}</p>

<div class="vue-pane-wrapper">
  <router-view
    v-slot="{ Component, route }"
    :input_binding="input_binding">
  </router-view>
</div>

<template>
  <div id="vue-route-home">
    <div class="vue-pane">
      <h3>This is the route vue-route-home</h3>
      <input v-model="input_binding" placeholder="edit me" />
      <p>Message inside route vue-route-home is: <span v-html="'{{ input_binding }}'"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="vue-route-barchart">
    <div class="vue-pane">
      <h3>This is the route vue-route-barchart</h3>
      <input v-model="input_binding" placeholder="edit me" />
      <p>Message inside route vue-route-barchart is: <span v-html="'{{ input_binding }}'"></span></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

My Vue Javascript looks like:

```
const LineChart = {
  props: [
    'input_binding',
  ],
  template: '#vue-route-home'
}
const BarChart = {
  props: [
    'input_binding',
  ],
  template: '#vue-route-barchart'
}

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: LineChart,
  },
  {
    path: '/bar-chart',
    component: BarChart,
  },
]

const router = VueRouter.createRouter({
  history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});

this.vue = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      input_binding: "This uses input binding.",
    };
  }
}).use(router).mount('#app');
```

Outside my Vue Router template, I am using:

```
<input v-model="input_binding" placeholder="edit me" />
<p>Message (outside route) is: {{ input_binding }}</p>
```

And the data binding works fine as in https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html#basic-usage

However in my template I need to change this to:

```
<input v-model="input_binding" placeholder="edit me" />
<p>Message inside route vue-route-barchart is: <span v-html="'{{ input_binding }}'"></span></p>
```

That is, I am escaping `{{ input_binding }}`, otherwise it seems to get rendered as text and then not change at all.

But now the input item does not bind, it is as if `v-model="input_binding"` is completely ignored.

I tried the following without success:

```
<span v-html="'<input v-model="input_binding" placeholder="edit me" />'"></span>
```

But this seems like a hack, and Vue does not allow characters like `<` to be included as escaped HTML.

Comment: Two-way binding in v-model presumes that a child should emit an event. You kill this possibility by doing it one-way, `:input_binding="input_binding"`. Probably something like `<router-view v-model=...` could work but I'm not sure at all. I doubt that the router was meant for this kind of usage. "But this seems like a hack" - not a hack but mistake, v-html is for html, it's not supposed to handle Vue templates, this is a job for the compiler.

Comment: This is the case for global state. Either Vuex or your own with provide/inject.